# Is there any way to return a user defined function content (query) on Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, user-defined-functions

I need to visualize the user defined funtion query, but in the moment I can see only the UDF's name using:

```
SELECT
    proname
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
    JOIN
        pg_catalog.pg_proc p
    ON  pronamespace = n.oid
WHERE
    nspname = 'public';
```

Comment: In Postgres, the column `pg_proc.prosrc` contains that